# How to resolve Azure domain verification error

Tags: azure, dns, directory, azure-active-directory

I was try to register a domain but got:
"Could not verify this domain because it was previously configured for your tenant or for another tenant."

That domain was created and deleted a few days ago without successful verify.

Now I try to register the same domain again with the new TXT destination text string, but got the above error message.

Anyone can help?

Thanks

Comment: Each custom domain can only be used in one Azure AD tenant and you can’t add the same domain to multiple Windows Azure AD tenants. You had better check this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/35ae2ac6-cdaf-4d1f-9e0a-ff530bb57237/could-not-verify-this-domain-because-it-was-previously-configured-for-your-tenant-or-for-another?forum=WindowsAzureAD).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both your DNS and your Domain are on the same subscription, if both hosted within Azure. This has led me on a wild goose chase one too many times.